# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I"m trying to use the template in typeahead but I have this error : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The script is :

```
var countriesBasic = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d) { return d.tokens; },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: 'assets/json/countries.json'
    });

countriesBasic.initialize();

$('#countriesList').typeahead(null, {
      name: 'countries',
      displayKey: 'name',
      source: countriesBasic.ttAdapter(),
      templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
          '<p class="country-name">{{name}}</p>',
          '<p class="country-iso">{{iso}}</p>',
          '<p class="country-description">{{capital}}</p>'
        ].join(''))
      }
});
```

The json file is

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "iso": "US",
    "capital": "Washington",
    "name": "United States"
},{
    "id": 2,
    "iso": "FR",
    "capital": "Paris",
    "name": "France"
}]
```

It seems there is a bug in my json file because when i use the file from demo it works but I don't see the problem...

Comment: usually the console tells you the line where the error occurs..

Comment: There is no even a single `.length` usage in this code.

Comment: I'm guessing it's related to `d.tokens` wherein `tokens` is not a data property.

Comment: Tomanow thanx. by changing  the datnumtokenizer with           `datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); }` it works

Comment: @Lolo You should answer your own question to let people know that you have a fix.